# Unable to get provider mono.MonoRuntimeProvider

Tags: android, xamarin.android

I am getting error 'evaluation version requires targeting the shared runtime' on `monoadndroid` when i try to build a package under release mode.
If i turn on `Use shared runtime` under `ProjectProperties > Mono Android Option`
The package successfully created.
But when i run it under android it give me error on start-up. The `log cat` shows the following error.

```
E/AndroidRuntime(  239): FATAL EXCEPTION: main

E/AndroidRuntime(  239): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to get provider mono.MonoRuntimeProvider: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to find application Mono.Android.DebugRuntime or Mono.Android.Platform.ApiLevel_8!
```

I am working on a evaluation version of MonoforAndroid!

Comment: sometimes when you hit these types of problems, it helps to turn fast deployment off

Comment: but can i install my APK file in android phone built on evaluation version of MonoforAndroid. My Debug run fine but after installing singed-apk using AVD manager. I am getting `Unable to get provider mono.MonoRuntimeProvider` via `log`.

Comment: not sure what you are trying to do? Are you trying to run on a real phone? In that case I think you should purchase an evaluation license - 30 day money back guarantee. Sorry if I've misunderstood but it's not clear from your question.